# How to access to the underlying grid table behind Mapinfo's Grid Thematic map?

Tags: raster, mapinfo, thematic-map

I created a grid thematic map using "Mapinfo - Map - Create Thematic Map" function. Now I want to know the distribution of the data from the grids.

But the "Browse Table" option is not functioning for the thematic map.
[image]

Is there a way to get access to the grid table used to create this map?

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo Pro doesn't allow you to "browse" the data behind a raster grid.

If you want to work with raster grids in MapInfo Pro, I would recommend that you take a look at MapInfo Pro Advanced which can be considered the 64-bit replacement for the "classic" 32-bit Vertical Mapper.

But maybe this tool can help you out for now: [Grid Analyser](http://www.mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&sobi2Id=469&Itemid=72) 
It's not exactly new so I'm not sure how well it works these days.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Peter! The Grid Analyser seems to be too old to run on my machine. I guess I'll have to generate the grid first, then use it to draw thematic map.